# Escaping for username and URL text boxes

Tags: php, html, security

My site got hacked a few times already and I'm using post comment on a flat file. I have tried to escape string in the past and, since I'm not using SQL, I can't use `mysql_real_escape_string`. However, I have tried many other ways to keep the string free from stuff like this: `<#$()[]{},.;!`. I use the code as you can see below:

```
$newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ta'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

I also use this:

```
$search = array("!", "$", "%", "(", ")");
$URLS = str_replace($search, " ", $url);
```

Finally, I use this:

```
if (keychar == "`" || keychar =="#" || keychar =="^" || keychar =="*") {
```

None of them seem to work and my site still got hacked. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction.

I believe the `textarea` is fine. I'm not 100% sure but I do know the URL textbox for pix and username is vulnerable. I'm trying to learn how to close up all vulnerability and as you can see it isn't working.

```html
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%; 
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}  
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
fieldset {
 word-break: break-all;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:8px;
 box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
 width:97%;  
}
legend {
 background:#fff;
}
table {
    word-break: break-all; 
    width:97%;
    border:0;
    cellspacing:0;
    cellpadding:0; 
}
div {   
   overflow:hidden;
   border: solid 2px gray;
   padding: 1em; 
}   
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php    
// $date = "".date("F d Y H:i:s.");  
$date = "".date("g:ia \n l jS F Y") . "\n";   
$myfile = "file.txt";
if(isset($_POST['ta'])){
    if(isset($_POST['urls'])){
        $url = $_POST['urls'];  
    }
    $wordcount = str_word_count($_POST['ta']);
    $myfile ="file.txt";
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ta'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $nn = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['namee'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    // $fieldsetstring = 
    // $fieldsetfilter = htmlspecialchars($fieldsetstring, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $handle = fopen($myfile, 'a+');   
    // fwrite($handle,  '<fieldset><legend>Anonymous: ' . $date . '</legend>' . $newData . '</fieldset></br>');
    fwrite($handle, '<div><fieldset><legend><img src="'.$URLS.'"  width="42" height="42">' . $nn . ' : ' . $date . '</a></legend><table><tr><td><h1>' . $newData . '</h1></td></tr></table></fieldset></div></br>');
    fclose($handle);
}
?> 
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>   
<?php
if(file_exists("$myfile")){
   $myData = file_get_contents("$myfile");
}
?> 
<a></a>
<form action = "index.php" method = "POST"  style="align:center">
Username : <input type="text" name="namee" value="Anonymous" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return check(event)"/>
url : <input type="text" name="urls" value="http://findicons.com/files/icons/398/halloween/128/jack.png" style="text-align:center; width:30%" onkeypress="return check(event)" onkeyup="return check(event)"/></br>
<textarea name="ta" cols="64" rows="10"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried many escapes from Stack Overflow before I post this. In fact, I have been trying to figure this out for a month already and I'm sure it got hacked more than a few times. And that's just what I know. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function:

```
function protect($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

**UPDATE: Code Explanation**

The function just takes a variable or an argument and passes it through PHP's `trim`, `stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` functions. The returned variable is safe from possible injections.

Comment: I have try few injections on it after i insert that code and it seems to be working so far Thank you so much.

Comment: Code-only answer do very little to educate the OP and future SO readers.  Please take a moment to improve your answer and explain what your method does and why it is a good idea.